# Fragment Cast issue in viewpager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-listfragment

I'm new to the android development. In my app there are two tabs(i use **view pager** to develop this tab) and each tab contains list(FragmentA and FragmentC)(i used **listfragment**). when pressing/clicking the each list item in both tabs it navigate to new fragment(FragmentB) and display all contains of the clicked list view item.

i have used Communicator interface to communicate fragment and mainactivity. First fragment pass data to main activity and then activity pass data to second fragment.

My problem:
first fragment(FragmentA- listfragment) pass data to main actitvty . But when main activity tries to pass data to second fragment(FragmentB) it give error. FragmentA can not be cast to FragmentB. I tried to find a solution several days. but i was unable to find a proper solution for this.

**Communicator Interface**

```
public interface Communicator {
    void sendData(String msg);
}
```

**FragmentA.java**

```
package com.example.tab;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * 
 */
public class FragmentA extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener {

    public FragmentA() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    ListView listView;
    Communicator com;
    View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_a, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(),
                R.array.books, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onAttach(activity);
        com = (Communicator) getActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        com.sendData("Hello");

    }

}
```

**FragmentB.java**

```
package com.example.tab;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * 
 */
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {

    public FragmentB() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    TextView textView;
    Context context;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        context = getActivity().getBaseContext();
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
        textView=   (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
        return view;
    }

    public void setData(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        textView.setText(msg);
    }

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.tab;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements TabListener,
        Communicator {

    ViewPager viewPager;
    ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
        viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(arg0);
            }

            public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.setTitle("");

        ActionBar.Tab tab1 = actionBar.newTab().setText("1-50")
                .setTabListener(this);
        ActionBar.Tab tab2 = actionBar.newTab().setText("50-100")
                .setTabListener(this);

        actionBar.addTab(tab1);
        actionBar.addTab(tab2);
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0xff7e3e00));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void sendData(String msg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try {
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentB fragmentB = (FragmentB) manager
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.pager);
            fragmentB.setData(msg);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    }
}

class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        Fragment fragment = null;

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (arg0 == 0) {
            fragment = new FragmentA();
        }
        if (arg0 == 1) {
            fragment = new FragmentC();
        }
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 2;
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.tab.MainActivity" >

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

**Error Message**

> com.example.tab.FragmentA cannot be cast to com.example.tab.FragmentB

Full Logcat:

```
01-18 13:21:03.380: D/AndroidRuntime(15257): Shutting down VM
01-18 13:21:03.380: W/dalvikvm(15257): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41572ba8)
01-18 13:21:03.390: E/AndroidRuntime(15257): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-18 13:21:03.390: E/AndroidRuntime(15257): Process: com.example.tab, PID: 15257
01-18 13:21:03.390: E/AndroidRuntime(15257): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.tab.FragmentA cannot be cast to com.example.tab.FragmentB
01-18 13:21:03.390: E/AndroidRuntime(15257):    at com.example.tab.MainActivity.sendData(MainActivity.java:105)
01-18 13:21:03.390: E/AndroidRuntime(15257):    at com.example.tab.FragmentA.onItemClick(FragmentA.java:52)
01-18 13:21:03.390: E/AndroidRuntime(15257):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:299)
01-18 13:21:03.390: E/AndroidRuntime(15257):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1113)
01-18 13:21:03.390: E/AndroidRuntime(15257):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2911)
01-18 13:21:03.390: E/AndroidRuntime(15257):    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3645)
01-18 13:21:03.390: E/AndroidRuntime(15257):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-18 13:21:03.390: E/AndroidRuntime(15257):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-18 13:21:03.390: E/AndroidRuntime(15257):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-18 13:21:03.390: E/AndroidRuntime(15257):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
01-18 13:21:03.390: E/AndroidRuntime(15257):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-18 13:21:03.390: E/AndroidRuntime(15257):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-18 13:21:03.390: E/AndroidRuntime(15257):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
01-18 13:21:03.390: E/AndroidRuntime(15257):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
01-18 13:21:03.390: E/AndroidRuntime(15257):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

after debugging i can see error will occur from this line

```
FragmentB fragmentB = (FragmentB) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.pager);
```

Comment: which line u are getting this error....post d full logcat

Answer (score 1):

Your are not attaching the FragmentB to Activity. The flow should be like this

1.Create a fragment which holds the viewpager(ViewPagerFragment.java)

2.In activity(activity_main.xml) you should create a FrameLayout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>
```

3.In oncreate method of Activity add this code which will add the viewpager Fragment to activity

```
   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, new ViewPagerFragment())
            .commit();
```

Dont forget to change the viewpager parameter to **getChildFragmentManager()**

4.The from FragmentA up on list click call this method and this will replace the ViewPagerFragment with new one(FragmentB)

```
@Override
public void sendData(String msg) {
    try {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, new FragmentB().newInstance(msg));
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

Change the FragmentB to this.

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    String mParam;

    public static FragmentB newInstance(String param1) {
        FragmentB fragment = new FragmentB();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_b, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: FragmentB in not List Fragment and it should be replaced in FragmentA. I think you got my point